# Installing different iconv in same RedHat box

Tags: linux, rhel, software-installation, rpm, glibc

I have new version of `iconv` installed in RedHat 8 (production). How can I **downgrade without affecting existing** `iconv` (as well as existing `glibc`) ?

Currently I have this:

```
iconv 2.28
RedHat 8.5
```

Need to move to:

```
iconv 2.22
```

Same linux box without effecting old version.
I am okay to use the command as `iconv_old` or `/home/smily/iconv` . It should work somehow, that's all!

It would be great, if you can provide the commands I should try.
I searched for adding it to Yum, but couldn't get a solution.

There are rpm files of `glibc` but I am not sure how to install (multiple versions) and which one I should download.